# Check if AMQ Artemis broker is healthy using Jolokia through TCP connection

Tags: java, openshift, activemq-artemis

We have an Openshift project ( project1 ) in which we setup an AMQ Artemis broker using the image : amq- amq-broker-7-tech-preview/amq-broker-71-openshif . Being the basic image we don't have any configuration such as SSL or TLS. In order to do the setup we used as example : https://github.com/jboss-container-images/jboss-amq-7-broker-openshift-image/blob/amq71-dev/templates/amq-broker-71-basic.yaml

After the deployment of the image on Openshift we have the following:

- broker-amq-amqp (5672/TCP 5672) No route
- broker-amq-jolokia (8161/TCP 8161) No Route
- broker-amq-mqtt ( 1883/TCP 1883 ) No route
- broker-amq-stomp ( 61613/TCP 61613 ) No route
- broker-amq-tcp ( 61616/TCP 61616 ) No route

My question is : how we can check if the broker is healthy using the TCP connection to broker-amq-jolokia ? So far we connected using TCP Sockets in Java to broker-amq-jolokia but we don't know what message in order for Jolokia to respond with the health status of the broker

Comment: Why are you using such an old version? Have you already taken a look at https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker-kubernetes-image?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis has a lot of beans exposed by jolokia and they can be used to perform the required health checks.

For a standalone broker could be useful to check:

- the broker is started `console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"$BROKER_NAME\"/Started`
- the disk store usage `console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"$BROKER_NAME\"/DiskStoreUsage`
- the address memory usage `console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"$BROKER_NAME\"/AddressMemoryUsagePercentage`

For a cluster of brokers could be useful to check the topology:
`console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"$BROKER_NAME\"/listNetworkTopology`

All this checks and others can be executed using the tool `artemis check`, ie:

```
./bin/artemis check queue --name TEST --produce 1000 --browse 1000 --consume 1000 --url tcp://$BROKER_IP:61616
```